# react native screen load function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

hi I wanna check if  user not logged in navigate the user to the login screen but when the app first opens user will navigate to the login screen 
how run a code only if a screen loaded

```
componentDidMount(){


AsyncStorage.getItem('islogin', (err, result) => {
  console.log(result);
  if (result!==true){
    this.setState({login:false})

   }
  }); 
}

render() {
  if(this.state.login==false){

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    navigate('profile',{ name: 'cat' }) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

move your code into componentWillReceiveProps. on navigation, your component will receive new props and componentWillReceiveProps will be called. so here you can check AsyncStorage and navigate user.

```
componentDidMount(){
  AsyncStorage.getItem('islogin', (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
    if (result!==true){
      this.setState({login:false})           
     }
   }); 
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextStates) {
  console.log(nextState)
  if(nextState.login == false)
    this.props.navigation.navigate('profile',{ name: 'cat' });
}
render() {

}
```

Comment: i console logged in componentWillReceiveProps. but never trigger

Comment: I thought you are using redux. shouldComponentUpdate will work for you. I added some code example

Comment: But react navigation tab change not remount component

Comment: no it's not remount component. TabNavigator screens are mounted when you open application.

Comment: So how i should check user is logged in every time he enter my tab

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` will be called on changing tabs. I'm developing a project like this right now and I get new props in `componentWillReceiveProps`. I'm using redux with react-navigation.

Comment: So its impossible with out redux?

Comment: I guess it should work without redux. because when you navigate this.props.navigation.state will be changed.

Comment: can you give me a simple redux navigation implement

Answer (score 0):

I am using `react-native-router-flux` for routing, You can do conditional state as described in code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import {Scene, Router} from 'react-native-router-flux';

//Splash
import Splash from '../splashscreen_component';


//Home
import HomeScreen from '../home_component/HomeScreen';

//Login
import Signin from '../login_component/Signin';

var KEY = 'isLIn';

export default class AppRoutes extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._loadInitialState().done();
  }

  async _loadInitialState() {
    try {
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(KEY);
      if (value !== null && value === 'true') {
        this.setState({isLoggedIn: true, isLoading: false});
      } else {
        this.setState({isLoggedIn: false, isLoading: false});
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:AsyncStorage:', error.message);
    }
  };

  _loginscreen() {
    return (
      <Scene key="root" hideNavBar hideTabBar>
        <Scene key="Signin" component={Signin} title="Signin" initial panHandlers={null}/>
        <Scene key="Home" component={HomeScreen} title="Home" panHandlers={null}/>

      </Scene>
    );
  }

  _homescreen() {
    return (
      <Scene key="root" hideNavBar hideTabBar>
        <Scene key="Home" component={HomeScreen} title="Home" initial panHandlers={null}/>

      </Scene>
    );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading === true) {
      return (<Splash/>);
    } else {
      if (this.state.isLoggedIn === true) {
        return (
          <Router>{this._homescreen()}</Router>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <Router>{this._loginscreen()}</Router>
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```